# Valgrind ARM binary not working in ARM926EJ, giving error as not found

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling, valgrind, memcheck

**Problem: Not able to run Valgrind binary in ARM.**

---

I cross compiled the `Valgrind-3-13-0` successfully in Linux host. And I moved the binaries to my ARM target. I ran Valgrind in the arm it says `not found.`

**Steps to cross-compile**

During the build process, I poked the configure file, changed `armv7` as `arm`.

```
./configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/home/my_dir
```

and I tried this option as well

```
 ./configure --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/my_dir
```

then make and make install.

I see Valgrind is located in my root file system `/usr/bin`, wondering why its saying not found.

---

This is the final output from the Valgrind cross-compilation. Below is just tree of my install dir.

```
target_val/
├── bin
├── include
│   └── valgrind
│       └── vki
├── lib
│   ├── pkgconfig
│   └── valgrind
└── share
    ├── doc
    │   └── valgrind
    │       └── html
    │           └── images
    └── man
        └── man1
```

---

I actually copied only five files from `/bin` dir to my target `/usr/bin`.

```
callgrind_annotate
callgrind_control
valgrind
valgrind-di-server
valgrind-listener
```

**Question.**

Do I need to copy the entire lib dir also?

I try to run the cross-compiled binary in host

```
usr:~/Desktop/ ./valgrind --version
/lib/ld-linux.so.3: No such file or directory
```

What I expected is it will complain like this  Invalid ELF image for this architecture because I built it for the arm and running it on Linux it should complain like this but it doesn't.

Wondering about configuration flags and the ARCH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon I posted the question in StackOverflow, I found the answer in five minutes.

---

**Valgrind support is available from armv7.**

---

**Actaully my hardware doesn't support Valgrind**, I just got confused by Amr7 and Armv7 both are not same. Its the same goes to ARM9E is not same as AMRv9. My bad.

I attached the [arm architecture page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ARM_microarchitectures) for reference.